# Tarski monster groups: for which primes they don't exist?

Tags: gr.group-theory

What can be said about the set of primes $p$ for which it is proven that an infinite group with all non-trivial proper subgroups cyclic of order $p$ doesn't exist? Specifically, what is the largest such $p$ (say $p_0$)? All I could find in the literature is $p_0\le 10^{75}$, but I admit I didn't look very far...

Comment: Aren't there small primes p > 700 for which the finitely generated infinite Burnside groups exist?  Or are you looking for p even and nonprime?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.17

Comment: Huh? p must be prime, as we are looking for "every subgroup"

Comment: I suspect that the largest prime for which this it is known that no Tarski Monster exists is 3 (but I might be wrong)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The largest known prime for which existence of Tarski monster is not known is $997$, see Adyan, S. I.; Lysënok, I. G. Groups, all of whose proper subgroups are finite cyclic.  Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 55 (1991), no. 5, 933--990; translation in Math. USSR-Izv. 39 (1992), no. 2, 905–957. There are currently no methods of proving that for a given prime $p$ a Tarski monster does not exist except for showing that all finitely generated groups of exponent $p$ are finite. This gives hope that the bound $997$ can be lowered to $665$ (or below $300$ assuming the recent Adian's announcement is correct).

Comment: Probably I should say that 1